# non-ui-updating functionalities such as reading a get property, is it require to execute in main thread

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, xcode9

I understand that all UI updating functionalities are necessary to be executed in main thread, but Xcode shows following warning on UI non-updating functionality

[image]

Really, is it true? that such basic functionalities that does not require updating UI (as below) needs to be executed in main thread

```
if UIButton.isEnabled {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIKit is not thread-safe so if you try to access UIView and its subclasses' properties in background thread you might end up reading outdated values since they could have been changed in the main thread.

Comment: Or if you make a call that changes the state of a UIView those state changes would be mis-applied. UIView objects have tons of state and lots of logic that depends on/alters that state, so they are VERY much not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. Pretty much all UIKit calls must be done on the main thread. If you are manipulating a UIView (or a subclass) it must be done on the main thread, for example.

The fact is that for a non thread-safe framework like UIKit, a lot more than just UI updating is forbidden from background threads. Any call that either reads or writes state of a UIKit object will cause threading problems, and is therefore forbidden.

Consider the fact that if you have an `Int` instance variable X the expression:

```
x += 1
```

...can cause problems if executed from a background thread because the processor has to read the value of X from memory, calculate a new value, and write the results back to memory.

It is possible that another thread might write a new value to the memory of `x` between those 2 steps, and that new value could be lost.

Concurrent programming is hard. If the docs say a framework is not thread-safe, don't call it from a background thread. Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But you can use it in this following way:-

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

// This is main Thread

    if (self.btnSave.isEnabled)
    {
         // Do Something
    }
});
```